# CSS- How floated are position relative to other folated objects

Tags: css

In the following code, why does div3 move down a line instead of div2. I am trying to understand how "clear" works in css. If I clear div3 and it moves to the next line, that makes since.

```css
 div {
   border: solid 1px red;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   margin: 5px;
 }
 div {
   float: left;
 }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tester</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="div3"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you clarify the question a bit? I don't really understand what you want to ask... A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would help!

Comment: @giorgio Your markdown syntax for links is backwards.

Comment: Thanks @JoshBurgess ;) too fast, too furious ;)

Comment: In the code you have provided, (a) there is no 'clear' defined, and (b) floating elements suck!

Comment: @jbutler483 your (b) is 1) a personal opinion and 2) quite a strange opinion, as without floats we couldn't create a lot of awesome (responsive) websites...

Comment: "Clear" and float can be confusing.  I've found this video to be the clearest explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xara4Z1b18I

Comment: @giorgio: I have managed (for quite some time) to get along without floating elements. There are things called Media Queries. And even if you don't like them, there's also percentage units and/or display options.

Comment: Sorry guys. What I meant to say was, when I applied :clear:both" to div2, it dragged div2, and div3 down to the second line, now, this happened yesterday in IE 11 but when I copied the same code to to another PC and ran it in IE 9, it worked as expected.

Comment: Still not being clear. What exactly happened in IE9? Why was it expected?

Comment: @v=xara4Z1b18I -I just watched the youtube video. If you go to the 2 minute he starts explaining about the clear property. You will see that applies clear:left  to the 3rd box(blue) and it moves to  the next line along with the 4th box. Why does the 4th one move down instead of moving over next to the green box?

Comment: @JRQ Go to the link that v=xara4Z1b18I posted and start at the 2 minute mark. When the third box is floated left, it drops down to the next line along with the 4th box. Why does the 4th box drop down instead of just moving over. How does "float:left" ont eh third box affect the 4th box?

Comment: @user2747044 I posted the video link.  The 4th box follows the 3rd box because it comes after it in the document. Simple as that.